# use wildcard in ElasticSearch index template aliases

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my index template(simplified):

```
{
  "template": "user-*",
  "mappings" : {
    "ESHOP_USER" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "nickname" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "createTime" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "updateTime" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases" : {
      "user-test-alias" : {
          "index" : "user-test*"
      },
      "user-prod-alias" : {
          "index" : "user-prod*"
      }
  }
}
```

**What I want to do:**

Indices with name pattern `user-*` share the same template, and I want to add `user-test-alias` to all indices with name pattern `user-test*`, and `user-prod-alias` to all indices with name pattern `user-prod*`.

**What I got:**

With above template, I got all indices with name pattern `user-*` getting two aliases: `user-test-alias` and `user-prod-alias`.

I knew if I split this template to test and prod templates, or use `POST /_aliases` after indices creation, I can solve the problem. But is there some way to achieve my goal with only one index template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to use 3 templates:

- one that is common to both environments
- one for test (just for the alias)
- one for prod (just for the alias as well)

First template (common) applied first:

```
{
  "template": "user-*",
  "order": 0,
  "mappings" : {
    "ESHOP_USER" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "nickname" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "createTime" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "updateTime" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second template (test alias) applied next:

```
{
  "template": "user-test-*",
  "order": 1,
  "aliases" : {
      "user-test-alias" : {
          "index" : "user-test*"
      }
  }
}
```

Third template (prod alias) applied next:

```
{
  "template": "user-prod-*",
  "order": 1,
  "aliases" : {
      "user-prod-alias" : {
          "index" : "user-prod*"
      }
  }
}
```